# golang mutex sometimes works?

Tags: go, maps, mutex

I have the following goroutine that SOMETIMES generates the dreaded "fatal error: concurrent map read and map write".  Traceback indicates its on the s := db.FileInfo... map reference.

```
func HMAC(source string, i int) {
    var value [4]byte
    var mutex sync.Mutex
    defer WG.Done()
    hash, err := HashString(source);
    if err != nil {
            log.Critical("HashString error: ",err)
    }
    log.Trace("Slice:",i,"Authentication hash =",hash)
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    mutex.Lock()    // Protect Map activity
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    s := db.FileInfo.Slices[SliceName]
    s.Block[i].HMAC = hash
    for j:=0; j<32; j++ {
            off := rand.Intn(DataLen-5)  // 4 should do, but be safe
            s.Block[i].Random[j].Offset = off
            for k:=0; k<4; k++ {
                    value[k] = source[off+k]
            }
            s.Block[i].Random[j].Value = value
    }
    db.FileInfo.Slices[SliceName] = s
}
```

The HashString(source) function is computationally intensive, so is appropriate as a goroutine.  The code after the mutex calls is all relatively trivial computationally, taking less than 1% of the time the HashString(source) call takes.  go vet is clean on the routine and its caller.

This function is called (32) times as follows:

```
    util.WG.Add(32)
    for i:=0; i<32; i++ {
            off := i*util.BlockLen
            go util.HMAC(string(tblock[off:off+util.BlockLen-1]),i)
    }
    util.WG.Wait()
```

I get the error about once out of every half-dozen or so invocations of the program, very inconsistantly.

Anybody spot what I've done wrong?  The SOMETIMES nature of this problem is perplexing me.  Oh, FWIW, its running on a 12 thread I7.  Also: go version go1.7.5 linux/amd64.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every execution of the function is going to create a new mutex, so it isn't actually protecting anything. You need to have the function always use the same mutex by creating it elsewhere (e.g., as a global variable).

Comment: Thanks Andy.  That occured to about 20 seconds after I laid down for the night...

Answer (score 0):

Make *mutex* variable not local in your function. This is fixed code:

```
var mutex sync.Mutex

func HMAC(source string, i int) {
    var value [4]byte
    // var mutex sync.Mutex
    defer WG.Done()
    ...
```